# UGC: NoSuchFieldError: HEADER_USER_ID

Tags: odata, ugc

I have configured UGC for a JSP website and I am getting the following error in the generated DCP. It seems to be looking for HEADER_USER_ID.

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /data/pub10/dcp/jsp/dcp295_4952.jsp at line 42
42:                     <ugc:Comments itemURI="tcm:10-4952">                    
43:                         <ol>
44:                             <ugc:ForEachComment>                            <li>

java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: HEADER_USER_ID
com.tridion.ugc.taglib.webservice.WebServiceClient.addHeaders(WebServiceClient.java:237)
com.tridion.ugc.taglib.webservice.WebServiceClient.getResponse(WebServiceClient.java:94)
com.tridion.ugc.taglib.webservice.CommentsRetriever.retrieveComments(CommentsRetriever.java:152)
com.tridion.ugc.taglib.UGCCommentsTag.doStartTag(UGCCommentsTag.java:97)
org.apache.jsp.data.pub10.dcp.jsp.dcp295_005f4952_jsp._jspx_meth_ugc_005fComments_005f0(dcp295_005f4952_jsp.java:171)
org.apache.jsp.data.pub10.dcp.jsp.dcp295_005f4952_jsp._jspService(dcp295_005f4952_jsp.java:147)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
com.tridion.ambientdata.web.AmbientDataServletFilter.doFilter(AmbientDataServletFilter.java:255)
```

Below is the source of one of the published DCPs. UGC is working in the CMS GUI. I can view/add/edit comments on contents thru the Comments tab. However I am unable to get it to work on the presentation side.

```xml
<%@ page import="java.util.*, java.io.*, java.sql.*, utilClassesV3.*, adminV3.tridion.*, 
  jxl.*, jxl.write.*, admin.*, tags.*, com.tridion.linking.*, com.tridion.web.jsp.JSPPage,
  com.tridion.dynamiccontent.ComponentPresentationAssembler" %>  
<%@ page import="org.apache.lucene.analysis.*, org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer, org.apache.lucene.document.*, 
  org.apache.lucene.index.*, org.apache.lucene.search.*, org.apache.lucene.queryparser.analyzing.*, 
  java.net.URLEncoder, SiteSearch.*, org.apache.lucene.analysis.CachingTokenFilter, 
  org.apache.lucene.analysis.TokenStream, org.apache.lucene.index.memory.MemoryIndex, 
  org.apache.lucene.search.highlight.*, org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory, org.apache.lucene.store.Directory, 
  org.apache.lucene.store.SimpleFSDirectory" %> 
<%@ taglib uri="cbktags" prefix="CBK"%>
<%@ taglib uri="ugc" prefix="ugc"%>
<%@ taglib uri="jstltags" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="tridiontags" prefix="tridion"%>
<%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=utf-8" language="java"%>

<%
  request.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
  Link link = null;
  PageLink pageLink = new PageLink(10);
  BinaryLink binaryLink = null, rootBinaryLink = null;
  BinaryLink enBinaryLink = null, arBinaryLink = null, frBinaryLink = null;
  PageLink enPageLink = null, arPageLink = null, frPageLink = null;
  binaryLink = new BinaryLink(10);
  rootBinaryLink = new BinaryLink(9);
  enBinaryLink = new BinaryLink(10);
  enPageLink = new PageLink(10);
  arBinaryLink = new BinaryLink(11);
  arPageLink = new PageLink(11);
  ComponentLink componentLink = new ComponentLink(10);
  String linkAsString = "", tempString = "", strTCMPageId = "", siteLanguage="en";
  int publicationId=10;
  strTCMPageId = (String)session.getAttribute("TCMPageId");
  if (strTCMPageId == null || strTCMPageId.length() == 0)
    strTCMPageId = "";

  ComponentPresentationAssembler cpAssembler;
  cpAssembler = new ComponentPresentationAssembler(new JSPPage(pageContext, strTCMPageId)); 
%>
```

```xml
<ugc:Comments itemURI="tcm:10-4952">                    
  <ol>
    <ugc:ForEachComment>
      <li>
        <ugc:Choose>                                            
          <ugc:When test="ugcUser equals ugcComment.User.Id">
            <!-- If the user is the comment author, show a form to edit the comment -->
            <form method="post" id="editCommentForm">
              <input type="hidden" name="commentIdtcm:10-4952" value=""/>
              <textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="editCommenttcm:10-4952"></textarea><br/>
              <input type="submit" value="Save comment"/>
            </form>
          </ugc:When>
          <ugc:Otherwise> 
            <!-- If this visitor did not submit this comment, simply display it. -->
          </ugc:Otherwise> 
        </ugc:Choose>                                   
        <br/>               
      </li>
    </ugc:ForEachComment>                       
  </ol>
</ugc:Comments>
```

As you see the generated DCP doesn't show code for `comment.content` or `comment.id`

Has anyone come across this?

### UPDATE 21/1/2013

Okay, so the reason why I was getting the above error was because I used `ugc_taglib.jar` from hotfix #2 and the remaining jars from 2011 SP1. Once I replaced all the jars from the hotfix, the error is gone.

Comment: Can you supply a little more detail and information, like sources of published pages/DCPs and where this error exactly occurs? Also is this the only issue or is UGC not working all together?

Comment: Hi Bart, Please see updated query.

Comment: a little bit of formatting would have helped in making it more readable for everybody, please see what I edited so you can do the same in the future

Comment: to keep everything relevant, I suggest you answer this question with your update from 21/1/2013 and accept that answer. Then please ask your second question in a separate question, so it can be addressed separately, since it is a totally different question and it is confusing to have answers on different questions in the same location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so the reason why I was getting the above error was because I used `ugc_taglib.jar` from hotfix #2 and the remaining jars from 2011 SP1. Once I replaced all the jars from the hotfix, the error is gone.

Answer (score 2):

If you created your Component Template using a DWT Template Building Block, then the `${` syntax will have been stripped in there most likely.

To get the original output like this again:

```xml
<ugc:Choose>
  <ugc:When test="ugcUser equals ugcComment.User.Id">
    <!-- If the user is the comment author, show a form to edit the comment -->
    <form method="post" id="editCommentForm">
      <input type="hidden" name="commentIdtcm:10-4952" value="${ugcComment.id}"/>
      <textarea rows="4" cols="30" name="editCommenttcm:10-4952">${ugcComment.content}</textarea><br/>
      <input type="submit" value="Save comment"/>
    </form>
  </ugc:When>
  <ugc:Otherwise> 
    <!-- If this visitor did not submit this comment, simply display it. -->
    ${ugcComment.content}
  </ugc:Otherwise> 
</ugc:Choose>
```

You will have escape the `${` like this in your DWT TBB:

```
${'$'}{ugcComment.id}
```

or

```
@@'$'@@{ugcComment.id}
```

But be aware this only works correctly for Dynamic Component Templates or Page Templates. Since when you use this in an Embedded Component Template, the Page Template will resolve the `${` it sees again and you still end up with nothing in your output.

For Embedded Component Templates, you will have to escape it twice, like so:

```
${'$'}{'${'$'}'}{ugcComment.id}
```

or

```
@@'$'@@{'@@'$'@@'}{ugcComment.id}
```

However the error you are getting seems to be pointing to yet another issue, I don't know exactly but it looks like `ugcUser` is not initialized at all.

Comment: Hi Bart, Thanks for the update. We haven't used a DWT to get the UGC code but instead we are using a C# TBB to output the UGC code. I tried to escape the tag twice like you mentioned and this time, I was able to see the tag in the generated DCP. But when I access the DCP on a browser, it throws the same exception shown above at this line >> <ugc:Comments itemURI="tcm:10-4952">   and when UGCCommentsTag.doStartTag(). Is there something wrong with the syntax.

Comment: Please see update.